# CAML for Library within Library

Tags: caml-query, caml

I need help writing a CAML. Unfortunately, I have little experience with this and can't seem to formulate a query that works.

I'm trying to show a library that is within another document library. I have document library (1) selected but need the document library (2) within the query to only show those docs. I have this:

```
<Query>
<Where>
<FieldRef Name= 'documentlibrary(2)'>
</FieldRef>
</Where>
</Query>
```

I also need the query to only show 6 items of the folder and the most recent.

Comment: Hi, could you try to explain a bit further on how this is set up? It is not possible to have a library inside a library, maybe it is a lookup column?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you want to filter on a folder inside a library. To do that, use the following syntax:

```
<View Scope="RecursiveAll">
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="FileDirRef" />
        <Value Type="Text">/full/path/to/your/folder</Value>
      </Eq>
    </Where>
  </Query>
  <OrderBy>
    <FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='False'/>
  </OrderBy>
  <RowLimit>6</RowLimit>
</View>
```

We have three main parts here, inside the main `View` tag. That one itself has the scope set to "RecursiveAll" to include all items inside folders.

The `Query` tag says which items to return. Here we are saying to return anything that has the field `FileDirRef`(Folder) matching our value string.

`OrderBy` here is to sort by last modified date, descending (Ascending = False)

Finally, `RowLimit` is set to only include 6 items. It should be the last 6 modified ones because of OrderBy

Hope this answered your question.